# Plot horizontal line based on higher time frame inside a lower timeframe chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to plot a 100 10-minute bar high horizontal line into a 5-minute chart.

To get 100bar high, the pinescript code is as below;

`recent_high = ta.highest(close, 100)`

However, I don't know how to specify it as 10-minute bar and plot it inside 5-minute chart.

I am using Pinescript v5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `request.security()` function to request data from higher timeframe:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

recent_high = ta.highest(close, 100)
recent_high_10_min_tf = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "10", recent_high)

plot(recent_high_10_min_tf)
```

Comment: Thanks. Tested your code and verified that it works fine.